# Rewrite with class alias?

Tags: magento-1, overrides, xml, class-alias

In an extension I have a rewrite for `Mage_Sales_Block_Order_Info`.

```
<config>
  <global>
    <blocks>
      <sales>
        <rewrite>
          <order_info>Company_Module_Block_Sales_Order_Info</order_info>
        </rewrite>
      </sales>
    </blocks>
  </global>
</config>
```

This works as expected, however in the interest of extensibility for module users, I've tried this instead to no avail

```
<config>
  <global>
    <blocks>
      <company_module>
        <class>Company_Module_Block</class>
      </company_module>
      <sales>
        <rewrite>
          <order_info>company_module/order_info</order_info>
        </rewrite>
      </sales>
    </blocks>
  </global>
</config>
```

In this case Magento is throwing an Exception

> exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type:
>   company_module/order_info'

My question is twofold

1. Am I simply declaring this rewrite incorrectly when trying to use the class alias notation?
2. Is using the class alias notation for a rewrite actually pointless here? My thought is users of the module might use the same override notation I have, then extend my module's `Company_Module_Block_Sales_Order_Info` class instead of `Mage_Block_Sales_Order_Info` since Magento is looking for the `sales/order_info` alias in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it's incorrect and pointless. A rewrite assigns your *class*  to a *class alias*. While in theory this could be transitive, it would not provide any additional value. If another module wants to rewrite your class it actually has to rewrite the original class (alias) and depend on your module to take precedence.

Comment: Perfect that's what I thought! Just want to double check to ensure I'm getting my head around the rewrite and class alias concepts.